# When trying to show a view (edit.blade.php) containing a Laravel Collective form, gives 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()' - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective

When clicking the edit button in show.blade.php it should show edit.blade.php, but gives 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()'

Everything else works...
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**Whole error msg:** ErrorException
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: Real-estate/resources/views/properties/edit.blade.php) (127.0.0.1:8000/properties/8/edit)

**The foreach loop** (in: vendor/laravelcollective/html/src/FormBuilder.php:656)

```
foreach ($list as $value => $display) {

     $optionAttributes = $optionsAttributes[$value] ?? [];

     $optgroupAttributes = $optgroupsAttributes[$value] ?? [];

     $html[] = $this->getSelectOption($display, $value, $selected, $optionAttributes, $optgroupAttributes);
}
```

**Views**

show.blade.php

```
<a href="/properties/{{ $property->id }}/edit" class="btn btn-light">Edit</a>
```

edit.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['PropertiesController@update', $property->id], 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}  
        // a bunch of <div class="form-group"></div> go here
        {{ Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT') }}
        {{ Form::submit('Done', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

create.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'PropertiesController@store', 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
       // a bunch of <div class="form-group"></div> go here
       {{ Form::submit('Publish', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }} 
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $property = new Property;
    $property->title = $request->input('title');
    .
    .
    .
    $property->save();
    return redirect('/home');
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $property = Property::find($id);
    $property->title = $request->input('title');
    .
    .
    .
    $property->save();
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

**dd($property) before $property->save(); in public function store() above**

```
App\Property {#1204 ▼
  #table: "properties"
  +primaryKey: "id"
  #connection: null
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:10 [▼
    "title" => "Nice House"
    "reference_no" => "1234"
    "published_date" => "2021-06-04"
    "price" => "400k"
    "property_type" => "example"
    "area" => "example"
    "city" => "Example city"
    "description" => "example"
    "images" => "noimage.jpg"
    "user_id" => 2
  ]
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please give us the whole error message and show us the foreach?

Comment: Sure, I edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem is now solved. The error was caused by a wrongly configured form field: `{{ Form::select }}` in **create.blade.php**. I was missing `null`, so it should be:
`{{ Form::select('city', ['Example City 1' => 'Example City 1', 'Example City 2' => 'Example City 2' ], null, ['placeholder' => 'Select city...']) }}`

Answer (score 0):

Can you check what the value of `$list` is?

EDIT:

`$list` returns a string.

```php
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

When using above shown example, `$array` is the array used by the foreach, `$key` is each array item's key name and `$value` is it's corresponding value.

In your case, this is:

```php
foreach ($list as $value => $display) {
    ...
}
```

When you're trying to get the array's key (`$value`) and value (`$display`), it receives the **invalid argument supplied for** the **foreach()**.

Comment: With var_dump($list); die(); before the loop?

Comment: For example, yeah.
Or a simple solution would be to use `dd($list)`.
This executes `dump($list)` and `die()` in one call.

Let me know what you get as response.

Comment: I get a string, a city name.

Comment: So if I understand you right, you dumped `$list`, which returned a string, and you want to execute a foreach on it and use its index and value?
What exactly do you use the foreach and `$list` for?
If you use `foreach($array as $key=>$value) { // Do stuff }`, this returns `$key` as the array's key values and `$value` as it's corresponding value.
So in your case you get the error because it's trying to get the index and value of `$list`, which is a string.

Comment: What do you get returned when you'd `dd()` on `$property` before you execute `$property->save();`?

Comment: I added the result of dd();

Comment: Alright, and I'm guessing there is some route in your web.php which links `properties/{{ $property->id }}/edit` to a controller executing a function to show your view?
What else do you pass in this function?

Comment: Yes, properties/{{ $property->id }}/edit is the 'Edit' button that looks at a function in the Controller which returns the page/view edit.blade.php. Then a POST request in edit.blade calls in the controller the function update, which you can see above where I pass input values from the form.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question: "What else do you pass in this function?". This is the function: `public function edit($id) { $property = Property::find($id);  return view('/properties/edit')->with('property', $property); }` and $id is predetermined by the framework.